# Let user choose to update Service Worker

Tags: service-worker

Is it possible to let user to choose when to update Service Worker?

Why? I want to add economy mode which means that user could choose to save a lot of bandwidth. This could be useful when user's limit is almost full or he/she is using expensive internet abroad.

That's because if Service Worker updates and there are new assets' versions, it will download all of them which could be several MB. If you're 3 days and 50MB away from new month, every MB counts.

---

Let's say that I can retrieve the setting from localStorage:

```
const economy = localStorage.getItem(economy) || false
```

**How to let Service Worker know that it should only update itself if economy is true?**

---

I kind of realize that it could be a problem in a long run (outdated versions) but Im planning to annoy the user often if he/she doesn't want to update. I just want to add the option for user to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to handle updating/deleting (perhaps just a subset of) cache entries outside of the `install` and `activate` events, you have more flexibility as to when they should be triggered. You actually don't have to perform the updates in the service worker at all, if it ends up being easier for you not to. Individual webpages have access to the exact same [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) instances that the service worker for a given origin uses. You can modify the caches directly from the page in response to whatever action makes the most sense for you, e.g.:

```
// Ensure we have access to the Cache Storage API.
if ('caches' in window) {
  // Swap this out for whatever UI element will trigger the update.
  const el = document.querySelector('#update-caches-button');
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.caches.open('my-cache').then(cache => {
      // Add or delete entries from cache.
    });
  });
}
```

You could do something similar, but keep all the logic in the service worker, by using [`postMessage()`](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/) from a client page to trigger a service worker's `message` event, and then update the caches in the `message` event handler.

There are some advantages to relying on the `install`/`activate` events for performing cache management. In particular, you can rely on the service worker staying in a ["waiting" state](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#waiting) while there are other active clients that rely on the previous cache state, and don't have to worry about throwing away entries that will be needed by those other clients or swapping out the expected version of a resource for a new version while it's still being used. But as a developer, ultimately you're responsible for understanding how your cached resources are being used, and if the assets you're managing in these caches aren't likely to cause problems if there's a version mismatch or if something that was deleted by one tab needs to be retrieved from the network later on by another tab, then you're free to implement that sort of approach.

For what it's worth, we've thought about similar issues when implementing precaching/updates in [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache). There's some background at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues/145 about trying to make use of standard signals exposed by browsers indicating that the user prefers to conserve data, rather than everyone coming up with their own heuristics.